# Trilateration with limits?

Tags: math, distance, triangulation, approximation, trilateration

I'm in need of help solving an issue, the problem came up doing one of my small robot experiments, the basic idea, is that each little robot has the ability to approximate the distance, from themselves to an object, however the approximate I'm getting is way too rough, and I'm hoping to calculate something more accurate.

So:
**Input:** A list of vertex `(v_1, v_2, ... v_n)`, a vertex `v_*` (robots)
**Output:** The coordinates for the unknown vertex `v_*` (object)

Each vertex `v_1` to `v_n`'s coordinates are well known (supplied by calling `getX()` and `getY()` on the vertex), and its possible to get the approximate range to `v_*` by calling; `getApproximateDistance(v_*)`, function `getApproximateDistance()` returns two variables variables, that is; `minDistance` and `maxDistance`. - The actual distance lies in between these.

So what I've been trying to do to obtain the coordinates for `v_*`, is to use trilateration, however I can't seem to find a formula for doing trilateration with limits (lower and upperbound), so that's really what I'm looking for (not really good enough at math, to figure it out myself).

Note: is triangulation the way to go instead?
Note: I would possibly love to know a way to do, performance/accuracy trade-offs.

An example of data:

```
[Vertex . `getX()` . `getY()` . `minDistance` . `maxDistance`]
[`v_1`  .  2       .  2       .  0.5          .  1  ]
[`v_2`  .  1       .  2       .  0.3          .  1  ]
[`v_3`  .  1.5     .  1       .  0.3          .  0.5]
```

Picture to show data: http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/6414/unavngivetcb.png

It's obvious that the approximate for `v_1` can be better, than `[0.5; 1]`, as the figure that the above data creates is small cut of a annulus (limited by `v_3`), however how would I calculate that, and possibly find the approximate within that figure (this figure is possibly concave)?

Would this be better suited for MathOverflow?

Comment: Head on over to math.stackexchange.com - they'll be all over this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a simple discrete approach. The implicit formula for an annulus is trivial and the intersection of multiple annulus if the number of them is high can be computed somewhat efficently with a scanline based approach.

For getting high accuracy with a fast computation an option could be using a multiresolution approach (i.e. first starting in low-res and then recomputing in high-res only samples that are close to a valid point.

A small python toy I wrote can generate a 400x400 pixel image of the intersection area in about 0.5 secs (this is the kind of computation that would get a 100x speedup if done with C).

[image]

```
# x, y, r0, r1
data = [(2.0, 2.0, 0.5, 1.0),
        (1.0, 2.0, 0.3, 1.0),
        (1.5, 1.0, 0.3, 0.5)]

x0 = max(x - r1 for x, y, r0, r1 in data)
y0 = max(y - r1 for x, y, r0, r1 in data)
x1 = min(x + r1 for x, y, r0, r1 in data)
y1 = min(y + r1 for x, y, r0, r1 in data)

def hit(x, y):
    for cx, cy, r0, r1 in data:
        if not (r0**2 <= ((x - cx)**2 + (y - cy)**2) <= r1**2):
            return False
    return True

res = 400
step = 16
white = chr(255)
grey = chr(192)
black = chr(0)
img = [black] * (res * res)

# Low-res pass
cells = {}
for i in xrange(0, res, step):
    y = y0 + i * (y1 - y0) / res
    for j in xrange(0, res, step):
        x = x0 + j * (x1 - x0) / res
        if hit(x, y):
            for h in xrange(-step*2, step*3, step):
                for v in xrange(-step*2, step*3, step):
                    cells[(i+v, j+h)] = True

# High-res pass
for i in xrange(0, res, step):
    for j in xrange(0, res, step):
        if cells.get((i, j), False):
            img[i * res + j] = grey
            img[(i + step - 1) * res + j] = grey
            img[(i + step - 1) * res + (j + step - 1)] = grey
            img[i * res + (j + step - 1)] = grey
            for v in xrange(step):
                y = y0 + (i + v) * (y1 - y0) / res
                for h in xrange(step):
                    x = x0 + (j + h) * (x1 - x0) / res
                    if hit(x, y):
                        img[(i + v)*res + (j + h)] = white

open("result.pgm", "wb").write(("P5\n%i %i 255\n" % (res, res)) +
                               "".join(img))
```

Another interesting option could be using a GPU if available. Starting from a white picture and drawing in black the exterior of each annulus will leave at the end the intersection area in white.

For example with Python/Qt the code for doing this computation is simply:

```
img = QImage(res, res, QImage.Format_RGB32)
dc = QPainter(img)
dc.fillRect(0, 0, res, res, QBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255)))
dc.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
dc.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0)))
for x, y, r0, r1 in data:
    xa1 = (x - r1 - x0) * res / (x1 - x0)
    xb1 = (x + r1 - x0) * res / (x1 - x0)
    ya1 = (y - r1 - y0) * res / (y1 - y0)
    yb1 = (y + r1 - y0) * res / (y1 - y0)
    xa0 = (x - r0 - x0) * res / (x1 - x0)
    xb0 = (x + r0 - x0) * res / (x1 - x0)
    ya0 = (y - r0 - y0) * res / (y1 - y0)
    yb0 = (y + r0 - y0) * res / (y1 - y0)
    p = QPainterPath()
    p.addEllipse(QRectF(xa0, ya0, xb0-xa0, yb0-ya0))
    p.addEllipse(QRectF(xa1, ya1, xb1-xa1, yb1-ya1))
    p.addRect(QRectF(0, 0, res, res))
    dc.drawPath(p)
```

and the computation part for an 800x800 resolution image takes about 8ms (and I'm not sure it's hardware accelerated).

If only the barycenter of the intersection is to be computed then there is no memory allocation at all. For example a "brute-force" approach is just a few lines of C

```
typedef struct TReading {
    double x, y, r0, r1;
} Reading;

int hit(double xx, double yy,
        Reading *readings, int num_readings)
{
    while (num_readings--)
    {
        double dx = xx - readings->x;
        double dy = yy - readings->y;
        double d2 = dx*dx + dy*dy;
        if (d2 < readings->r0 * readings->r0) return 0;
        if (d2 > readings->r1 * readings->r1) return 0;
        readings++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int computeLocation(Reading *readings, int num_readings,
                    int resolution,
                    double *result_x, double *result_y)
{
    // Compute bounding box of interesting zone
    double x0 = -1E20, y0 = -1E20, x1 = 1E20, y1 = 1E20;
    for (int i=0; i<num_readings; i++)
    {
        if (readings[i].x - readings[i].r1 > x0)
          x0 = readings[i].x - readings[i].r1;
        if (readings[i].y - readings[i].r1 > y0)
          y0 = readings[i].y - readings[i].r1;
        if (readings[i].x + readings[i].r1 < x1)
          x1 = readings[i].x + readings[i].r1;
        if (readings[i].y + readings[i].r1 < y1)
          y1 = readings[i].y + readings[i].r1;
    }

    // Scan processing
    double ax = 0, ay = 0;
    int total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<=resolution; i++)
    {
        double yy = y0 + i * (y1 - y0) / resolution;
        for (int j=0; j<=resolution; j++)
        {
            double xx = x0 + j * (x1 - x0) / resolution;
            if (hit(xx, yy, readings, num_readings))
            {
                ax += xx; ay += yy; total += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (total)
    {
        *result_x = ax / total;
        *result_y = ay / total;
    }
    return total;
}
```

And on my PC can compute the barycenter with `resolution = 100` in 0.08 ms (x=1.50000, y=1.383250) or with `resolution = 400` in 1.3ms (x=1.500000, y=1.383308). Of course a double-step speedup could be implemented even for the barycenter-only version.

Comment: Even tho its lovely getting a picture as output, how would I modify it to output a coordinate? - as described in the io analysis

Comment: Also my robots aren't running with gpu hardware, sadly ;)

Comment: Probably the average (barycenter) would be a reasonable choice (while it's true that in theory the barycenter may fall outside the acceptable area, given the concrete application I'd say this is not going to happen. Otherwise a good point could be the "most internal point" (i.e. the internal point that is the most distant from the excluded area); that point is however a little more annoying to compute (IMO the best way is using the Euclidean transform and pick the absolute maximum - still linear in the area of the bounding box of the result, but the algorithm is not trivial).

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is what I'm looking for, it may just be because I can't seem to figure how to apply what your saying, or maybe I'm just a bit scared of having to allocate a *huge* array of chars.

Comment: I've added a barycenter computing implementation in C that requires no memory allocation at all (simple brute-force). For computing the "most internal point" instead I think a viable solution would require the allocation of a matrix to be able to quickly compute the Euclidean distance transform.

Comment: I played around with the python, I'll try out the C, and just at a glace it seems perfect, but I'll give it a spin and if its ok, you'll get the accept and bounty ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would switch from "max/min" to trying to minimize an error function.  That gets you to the problem discussed at [Finding a point that best fits the intersection of n spheres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879633/finding-a-point-that-best-fits-the-intersection-of-n-spheres) which is more tractable than intersecting a series of complicated shapes.  (And what if one robot's sensor is messed up and it gives an impossible value?  That variation will still usually give a reasonable answer.)

Comment: Robot sensor readings are checked, and any unusable values will not be included, in the trilateration.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your case, but in a typical robotics application you're going to be reading sensors periodically and crunching the data. If that's the case, you're trying to estimate the location based on noisy data and that's a common problem. As a simple (less rigorous) method, you could take the existing position and adjust it toward or away from each known point. Take the measured distance to target minus the present distance to target, multiply that delta (error) by some value between 0 and 1, and move your estimated position that much toward the target. Repeat for each target. Then repeat each time you get a new set of measurements. The multiplier will have an effect like a low-pass filter, smaller values will give you a more stable position estimate with slower response to movement. For the distance, use the average of the min and max. If you can put tighter bounds on the range to one target, you can increase the multiplier closer to 1 for just that target.

This is of course a crude position estimator. The math guys can probably be more rigorous, but also more complicated. The solution is definitely not anything to do with intersecting areas and working with geometric shapes.